# Set protractor arguments debugging in visual studio code

Tags: protractor, visual-studio-code

I'm debugging a protractor solution in visual studio code. How I can do to pass the baseUrl as parameter in launch.json file?

This is my protractor.conf.js file

```
exports.config = {
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      //baseUrl: 'xxx',
      ...

    };
```

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch e2e Tests",
                "type": "node",
                "program": "node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js",
                "stopOnEntry": false,
                "args": ["protractor.conf.js","--baseUrl='pippo'" ],
                "cwd": ".",
                "runtimeExecutable": null,
                "isShellCommand": true,
                "runtimeArgs": [],
                "env": { },
                "sourceMaps": false,
                "outDir": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Was looking for this settings, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the runtime executable:

```
"runtimeExecutable": "node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
"args": ["--baseUrl=https://127.0.0.1"]
```

Comment: Thaks @alecxe, your answer is not completly correct, but make me on the right way: `"runtimeExecutable": "node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
"args": ["--baseUrl=https://127.0.0.1"], `

Comment: @SamueleCozzi yeah, I haven't ever used Visual Studio, but have seen questions about it and researched a little bit. It was still guessing and I'm glad it helped you to find a solution. Please provide it separately and accept your own answer.

Comment: Just a hint in case of problems: I had installed node version 5.3.0 and it crashed all the time before getting to the breakpoint. Installing node v4.4.6 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I use the default `launch.json` and alter just these two settings:

```
"program": "c:/Users/lee/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
"args": ["${workspaceRoot}/protractor.conf.js"],
```